# Worker manger doWork() method can't be executed, but onStartWork() is called multiple times

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am trying to schedule work when app start after 1 mint I need do some work it does not matter app still in the foreground or not but I need to do this take, but **I don't know why my doWork method not run**.but onStart mathod called multiple time

```
private void sacduleThePaddingNotifaction() {
    OneTimeWorkRequest postNotationWithDelay =
            new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(PostNotificationWork.class)
                    .setInitialDelay(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(postNotationWithDelay);


}
```

My worker class

```
public class PostNotificationWork extends Worker {
    @Override
    public void onStartWork(@NonNull WorkFinishedCallback callback) {
        Log.d("PostNotificationWork: ","onStartWork");//this called many times, some time 4 time 
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        Log.d("PostNotificationWork: ","Posting notification");
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

i am using `def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha07"`

Comment: if `doWork` is called on a background thread then trying to do a toast will cause an error. Remove that line and look just for the logging statement. Also allow for the call to the super type on this method : `onStartWork`

Comment: thank you for poting the mistake, and now its working and i already have removed the toest from production app,because tost need UI context to show up

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, and I don't have a `onStartWork()`method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try to update to this version 
  `def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha06"
  implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version"`
- Remove 
  `@Override
  public void onStartWork(@NonNull WorkFinishedCallback callback) {
      Log.d("PostNotificationWork: ","onStartWork");//this called many times, some time 4 time 
  }`
- Finally Try again

Comment: i am using alpha07  implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha07"
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-firebase:1.0.0-alpha07"

Comment: the problem was i haved override onStartWork(...) mathod

Answer (score 0):

Please do not override `onStartWork()`. Even if you do you need to call `super.onStartWork()`. We are still working on the ergonomics of the `NonBlockingWorker` API.

Comment: yas i notis that when i override the onStart it saying you can't call super so i remove onSuper  call that mean worker thread never start because it was unable to passback data using super keyword

Comment: You don't need to override `onStartWork()` at all.